# jQuery Error IE JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I run this JS in FF or Safari it works just right but in IE I get 'optionValue' is Null or not an Object.

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectBrand').change(function(){
        $.getJSON('Scripts/ajax_busquedas.php', {idMarca : $(this).val() }, function(j) {
            var options = '';
            var i = '';

            for (i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue +'">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
            }

            $('#selectCategory').html(options);
            $('#selectCategoy option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas on how I can start debugging this?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your Json, things like :

```
{"property1": 1, "property2":2,/*<-- see the extra 'trailing comma' */};
```

works in firefox, safari etc but throw erros in IE.

Comment: This is my JSON: $resultado .= "{optionValue: $id, optionDisplay: '$marca'},";

Comment: well as you can see i dont have that. might there be an issue with IE not reaching because of htaccess password?

Comment: '$marca'},";  <-- But you have!

Comment: look your generated json, it is probrally tha last braket has a extra * , * (i'm sorry I dont kno whow to call it LOL)

Comment: oh so the one outside the {} also counts?

Comment: [ {'optionValue': 0, 'optionDisplay': '-categorias-'},{'optionValue': 89, 'optionDisplay': 'Accesorios'},{'optionValue': 85, 'optionDisplay': 'Cámaras Digitales'}, ]

Comment: of course, if i'm not wrong, jquery parser your json with something like "({" + code_santinized + "})"

Comment: see, you have a array with the last element ends with a " , " (please someone tell me how could i call it)?

Comment: you can call it a trailing comma

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define `optionValue` and `optionDisplay` either within the scope of JSON call or define them as global variables like so:

```
var optionValue = '';
```